# Teams chatbot is successfully connecting to an ngrok URL, but I'm facing issues when trying to connect it to the main URL

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot, ngrok

I have developed a Teams chatbot that successfully connects to an ngrok URL, but I'm facing issues when trying to connect it to the main URL after deployment. The bot works as expected when I use the ngrok URL, but it fails to respond when I switch to the main URL
I've tested the ngrok URL and the main URL locally, and they both seem to be accessible.
The bot's code is written in python.
I've configured the bot's endpoint in the Teams developer portal to use the main URL.

What could be causing the bot to work with the ngrok URL but not with the main URL? Are there any specific configurations or checks I might be missing?

Comment: Tracking the question from here-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1350295/i-am-able-to-hit-teams-chat-bot-ngrok-endpoint-but